# Define a variable name in the Wordpress rewrite rule and keep it under control with regex

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

Suppose I support the following languages:

```
array( 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'ru' );
```

provided a support with the following coding,

```
function rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?lang=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rule' );
```

of course, it will accept all future prefixes. This includes `"/hello-world"`. Therefore, no link structure on the site does not work.

to resolve this issue, I need to accept the supported languages ​​from the above array.

**Let me explain myself**

```
function rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        preg_match(array( 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'ru' ), '^([^/]*)/?', $matches),
        'index.php?lang=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'rule' );
```

Of course, this is completely hypothetical, I know that it is not a correct spelling.

Comment: I do not understand your reqular expression. What should it accept?

Comment: `^(en|fr|de|ru)/?` ?

Comment: @splash58 I'll try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^(en|fr|de|ru)/([^/]+)/?$',
        'index.php?lang=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
```

such a rule should be added.